# Compound Words handling in ElasticSearch - treat both form "splitted" and "joined" as same

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I am using elasticsearch in my project for searching products. It's working great. Currently I am facing a problem with the compound words e.g "body wash" and "bodywash", "face wash" and "facewash" etc. Searching by "body wash" and "bodywash" producing different results. I need a trick by which both of the forms of the keywords be treated as same.

Is there any analyzer or any other options of doing it? It is not possible for me to gather all such kind of compound words and insert both of them in the index. I need an algorithmic solution. Is there any? please help.

Comment: one should be careful about that. Even in case of English those compounds not always are same, e.g. frame buffer and framebuffer, water craft and watercraft - not synonyms. Best way is to offer adjusted search that would  search for both variants ("May be you was looking for...?") How you do solve problem with other dialectics - "grey" and "gray" (which not always have same meaning), "armour" (which never means a vehicle) and "armor" (which can mean armored vehicle)?

Comment: " Best way is to offer adjusted search that would search for both variants ": yes I am looking for the same. Do you mean I need to store both form of words in my index and search by any form?

Comment: search for "frame buffer" is search by two keywords. "framebuffer" is a keyword. you should check if  adjacent keywords are creating existing index item if concatenated. Next, step depends the strategy you want to employ and on relevance, e.g. if  framebuffer search is more relevant than frame buffer, it would be preferred one

Comment: Okay got it. thanks. But one problem with this approach is if the input query string is "framebuffer" and by searching (say) no result found but there exists records with "frame buffer" then how will I decide from the input keyword where to break the word to attempt another search by "frame buffer"?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem with [Elastic Search synonym Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html). It's working as I expected but one condition is that I need to create the synonym dictionary manually.
Official documentation is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html)